# How to re-enable formatting in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-formatting

The way VS2017 autoformats C++, especially on paste, drove me nuts, so I disabled some of it, i.e. while in the options I changed multiple options. But now it does not format anything at all.

I tried reenabling with all options that seemed to remotely related (i.e. within Text-Editor C++), but nothing worked so far. Tried reen-/disabling ClangFormat as well. Alt+F8 still works.

(BTW, I am running VS as admin most of the times, even though that is not a perfect solution to be able to copy the binaries into the app-folder, but it is very handy for debugging. This might have mixed up the preferences??)

Previously I had no problems adjusting indentation and how to align code, and that also still does work when making  selection and manually triggering it. But it is not triggered any more on pressing return, closing curly braces or semicolons. Also tab without selection does nothing any more.

How to reenable auto-formatting?
What did I switch off?

Here is a screenshot of my current options:

[image: option screen]

Comment: Please be more specific about what formatting you want. "Auto-formatting" is very broad, as you can tell by the wealth of more specific options on offer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, that was excactly the problem. I lost track of what I changed.. and did not even notice when being more specific above (after your comment), although the word is there now: indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing is the setting for C++/Tabs/Indenting/**Smart**. 
That does the trick for me (I had set that to "Block").

I do not understand why the other settings (like e.g. "format on semicolon") are switched by this, but auto-formatting works again now.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Brace Completion" settings under the Advanced tab:
[image]

Also, check that "Automatic brace completion" is checked under General tab:
[image]